# WIN 10 Installation/Mouse & Keyboard not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, windows-installation

I am trying to install WIN 10 on my Asus E200HA.
When I bought the laptop, I got it with WIN 10.
I was using Linux Mint 18.1 for a while, but due to kernal issues, I was not getting sound, hence decided to go back to WIN 10.
I am trying to install windows 10 which downloaded from Microsoft.
It boot from USB & then shows the language screen, but both my touchpad & keyboard doesn't work.
I tried changing the BIOS options (Only few options are available) still that doesn't help.
Can someone please suggest me what can be done here..

Thanks...
Emmanual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wanted to let everyone know, driver was not there in the system despite of having WIN 10. Connected an ext keyboard & mouse & that worked..

Answer (score 0):

It may be an odd problem, but maybe some fancy drivers are required. Did you try to use an external USB keyboard or mouse?

Also, sometimes not every USB port is fully functional if not booted completly (especially on convertibles which is not the case as far as I could see for your laptop)

Comment: Hi guys, just wanted to let everyone know, driver was not there in the system despite of having WIN 10. Connected an ext keyboard & mouse & that worked..

Answer (score 0):

Reply for people with this problem in the future: (Found this thread via Google)
For me, it helped just to wait for around 5 minutes (+/- 5). I guess, it just needed some time to install the needed drivers.

Asus Prime X370-Pro and installed Windows 10 via DVD on a new Samsung 960 Evo 250GB.

Comment: What does "5 minutes (+/- 5)" mean?